# How to do Non contact USB wiretapping?

Tags: usb, measurement

I am relatively new to electronics but came up with this project, not for nefarious purposes but simply as a cool project. Simply put I want to try and read the data traveling through a USB cable with a non contact device (like a digital clamp meter but for dc). I have looked at Hall effect sensors as an option but I'm not sure they would be sensitive/ fast enough (since speed is the main issue). The constant 5 volt power line could be used as a baseline for detecting signals in the communications line. Are there any other alternatives to a Hall effect sensor in this scenario?

Comment: I don't see how Hall sensor will be helpful here.

Comment: Look up the signal speed for USB, and compare to the reaction time of a hall sensor.  Never mind the ballpark, those two aren't even in the same city.

Comment: You *might* be able to get something out of a near-field probe, but the speed is a problem.

Comment: What prevents you from attaching actual probes to USB signals?

Comment: I've broken out data running down a twisted pair by a close contact near-field loop running at hundreds of Mbps. Position is a biggy and small movements meant data loss. Really high speed comparators were needed but it was a bit flakey.

Comment: They have sniffing software that does this, and you don't need wires. Your going to see zero electric field outside of the shield, magnetic fields will probably be to noisy to see. And if I remember right, hall effect sensors are too slow for USB speeds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A clamp-on detector which does not break out the individual wires won't work. USB is differential. Signal is carried on two wires, one labelled + and the other -. The sum of the currents in the two signal wires is zero, so the net magnetic field is also zero (at any distance from the pair).

Comment: More, the differential pairs in the cable are SHIELDED, making the idea even less feasible. If the OP is talking about USB 3.0, then it is really far from reach. More, even with a dedicated break-out board (USB protocol analyzer) and direct tappng into wires, it is frequently difficult to get any reliable data at all without careful cable termination match. Next question is how to deal with all protocol overheadm syncs, Packet's IDs, CRCs, EOP, etc. A full-blown protocol analyzer must be developed before getting into any data.

Answer (score 2):

Task is design a differential amplifier, AC_coupled, 1mm by 10mm pickup plates, pressed against differential cable with 1mm separation of plate and the inside USB wire. Assume 5pF capacitance of the differential amplifier (tapoff).

Assume 1volt change in USB signal, with 0.1 volt/nanosecond SlewRate.

1) what is the pickoff capacitance (assume Er = 5).
C = E0 * Er * Area/Distance = 9e-12 * 5 * 10mm * 1mm/1mm = 45e-12 * 10mm

C = 45e-14 or 0.45pF.

With our input capacitance of 5pF, the attenuation ratio is 10:1. Thus one volt becomes 90 milliVolts. Our differential amplifier has 180 milliVolts input, +90mV on one input and -90mV on other input, plus crosstalk and environmental trash and KT Boltzmann/Johnson/Nyquist/thermal white Gaussian noise.

Assume 100MHz bandwidth, and Rnoise = 62 ohms [1nanovolt/rtHz], with 180mVpp input. 
Signal Chain Explorer computes this SNR
[image]

The circuit provides 14dB gain, using amplifier with F3dB of 100MHz (see the small left plot). The total thermal noise (see the right plot) produces output referred noise of 72uV, assuming amplifier noise contributions of 1 nanoVolt per rootHz (integrated to 56uV), and with Resistive divider contributions of 40uV and 20uV integrated. These 3, RootSumSquare RSS combined, is 72uV RMS.

The SNR, shown at top right of SignalChainExplorer screen, is 69dB. If you had only 10dB SNR, your BitErrorRate would be about 0.1% (1e-3). At 20dB, BER would be about 1e-8. Thus at 69dB (which assumes no external environmental upsets or VDD trash), you will have no BitErrors.

Beware of long 111111 and 00000 patterns. This is a high-pass-filter input (DC_blocked).

Note-----this assumes you are INSIDE THE SHIELD, and only 1mm from the two USB wires.

Comment: That's a great answer. I am glad that I specified "at any distance from the pair". Where I hope it's clear that I meant largeish distance.

Comment: Maybe, maybe before rolling out an advice for an amplifier design for a silly task, it is worth to study USB signaling specifications? Maybe to learn something about NRZI encoding, 2ns pulse width, 400 mV signal amplitudes, bit stuffing to eliminate "long 111111"? C'mon people, you can't be serious...

Comment: You can bet the "national agencies" have access to very high speed differential pairs, in the low to moderate Gigahertz range. Monitoring 2nS pulses (4nS 10101 rate, or 250MHz) is an easy task for non-opamp amplifiers. And imagine a SiGe version of the CA3011 Limiter IC.

Comment: My point is that even if you have a full-blown protocol analyzer connected via direct tap to USB wires, you will have a really HARD TIME to make sense out of packet content, wading through various network protocol layers and application layers . I wish a really good luck to "national agencies", to all 17 of them, to get any information out of this.

Comment: Harris Corp, in Melbourne FLA, developed a portable cell-site spoofer in a suitcase. Get close to your target, and the spoofer now takes over the cell-phone traffic, for easy monitoring. Never underestimate what $100Million and full access to the technology-jocks can achieve.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that may work for you is to use an antenna and amplifier to pick up the USB communications. Even with differential pairs and shielding, some of the communications signature will leak from the cable.

The challenge you will have is to differentiate the USB communications from all of the other electromagnetic emissions of the connected devices. Proximity, directivity, and bandpass filtering can help sift the signal from the noise although it will still be a challenge. But this technique is used in the craft.